# What is the CSS @media query for 28" display?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm searching for what's the code for a display 28", by code I mean the CSS `media query`, like this in the example.

Example:

```
@media (max-height: 1200px) and (min-width: 1920px) {

.nav-over {
    width: auto;
    float:right;
    margin-right: 420px;
  }

  .nav {
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right:400px;
  }

  .navbar-brand {
    margin-left: 250px;
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: 26" screen can be with different screen resolutions. Find out the resolution and write media query based on that values.

Comment: Isn't that the query for a 26" screen?

Comment: The most common resolution (CSS pixels are different from hardware pixels) would probably be 1920 x 1080

Comment: In this moment I'm using the resolution 3840 x 2160 but doesn't work

Comment: The screen display size, is not important, only the resolution matter

Comment: I would not advice you use height in `@media` unless you really know what you are doing.

Comment: What if that 26" screen is displaying at 800x600 resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is super specific and I would not recommend doing it, but the way to do it is this

If you calculate the DPI *(dots per inch)* you can use this [link](https://www.sven.de/dpi/) to get the DPI

For 28″ you get 1920 x 1080 measures at 78.68 DPI and 1200x960 is 54.88  DPI

So for 1200px you get something like:

```
@media screen 
    and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
    and (min-resolution: 53dpi)
    and (max-resolution: 60dpi) { 
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I wrong to write the inch of the display I'm searching for, the right is 28"

Comment: @Carlo17 Edited, but again, do not use this, this is too specific. You have to be less specific.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to run the following JS code on the 28" device to find the height and width:

```
let height = window.screen.availHeight;
let width = window.screen.availWidth;
console.log(height, width);
```

Comment: Yes, at least if you write `height` and `width` instead of `availHeight` and `availWidth`, otherwise you get only the desktop area without taskbar(s).